# I have log4j2.xml like this. what shhould I add the to see SQL query in the logger?

Tags: logging

I have the log4j2.xml like this.

```
<Logger name="org.springframework" level="info" additivity="false">
        <AppenderRef ref="console" />
</Logger>
<Logger name="org.hibernate.type" level="info" additivity="false">
        <AppenderRef ref="console" />
</Logger>
```

Comment: you want to save sql queries in your log files?

Comment: I want to print the Query on the console

Comment: I removed the <sql> tag since this isn't related to the SQL _language_. Consider a framework and/or dbms tag instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
<Logger name="org.hibernate.SQL" level="DEBUG" additivity="false">
    <AppenderRef ref="console" />
</Logger>
```

add statement of logging level 'DEBUG'